# Java difference between List and List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between `List` and `List<Object>` in java?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you've got two lists:

`List<Object> mainList = new ArrayList<Object>();`

and one with a raw type:

`List rawList = new ArrayList();`

Now let's do something like this:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(42);
mainList.addAll(intList);
rawList.addAll(intList);
```

But there is somewhere one more list which contains String objects:

`List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>()`.

When we try to call

`strList.addAll(mainList)`

we get a Compilation Error :

`The method addAll(Collection<? extends String>) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>)`.

But if we try to call

`strList.addAll(rawList)`

we get just a warning.

So if you are using only lists of objects in your application it's really no difference between List and List. But since Java 1.5 it's a good idea to use generics for providing compile-time type safety for your application.

Answer (score 3):

One particular danger of raw types (e.g. `List` without the `<?>`) is that raw types **disable checking even outside of their own declarations**

Ref:  [a Java Puzzler](http://strangeloop2010.com/system/talks/presentations/000/014/450/BlochLee-JavaPuzzlers.pdf) that shows the danger of raw types. (starts at page 13)  Short version: because a raw type was used in a statement, a generic type elsewhere was not evaluated by the compiler, and thus bizarre runtime exceptions happened.

Short answer: it's a warning to use a raw type, for good reason.  Use an unbounded wildcard `List<?>` in strong preference to a raw type `List`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is this:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

List<Object> b = a; // compile error

List c = a; // fine
```

`List<Object>` is not compatible with a `List` of any other parameter. However, a raw `List` is compatible with `List`s of all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is quite subtle. The more obivous of the two is `List<Object>` which ist a list of arbitrary objects (as every class has Object as super class). The difference to `List` now is that `List` is untyped and therefore no type checks at all are performed, which ultimately leads to certain warnings and can lead to weird runtime behavior. While Java knows that `List<Object>` is a list that might contain anything, it doesn't know that about a `List`. Because if you consider "old style" Java, what you know would call `List<String>` used to be called only `List`. And that's the difference between those two...`List<Object>` is defined to contain a wide spectrum of objects **on purpose**, while `List` isn't.

I hope that sort of clarifies the matter. If not, just tell us what's still unclear. :)

Comment: The technical term for using a generified type without a type parameter is using a "raw type".

Answer (score 1):

Generics in Java is important for better error checking before hand (at compile time) due to which, less time is spent during runtime checking and debugging.

So, there is no direct performance gains, but you are quickly able to catch errors.

Bottom line: It helps in speed up development.

I strongly recommend you to go through this: [Generics in the Java Programming Language [pdf]](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: How does `List<Object>` help to catch errors, though? Isn't `Object` the most ancestral class possible?

Comment: I think the OP means any type of object when he says: `List<Object>` and his question is more focused on why use generics.

Answer (score 0):

There are quiet some special treatments about raw types; there's no incentive to enumerate them all, since raw types are discouraged anyway.

Let's talk about a narrower problem, which is probably most pertinent: given an object, we mostly care about what methods we can invoke on it; for that purpose, is there any difference if its type is `List` or `List<Object>`?

The methods of `List<Object>` are methods of `List<E>` with E substituted with Object; The methods of raw type `List` is the erasure of methods of `List<E>`. So we have

```
List                                List<Object>

boolean add(Object)                 boolean add(Object)
Object get(int)                     Object get(int)
int size()                          int size()
boolean addAll(Collection)          boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Object>)
...                                 ...
```

most of their methods are the same! In that regard, the two types are hard to distinguish.