# Strange generics behaviour. Being erased early?

Tags: java, generics, javac, type-erasure

I ran into some strange behaviour of Java generics today. The following code compiles fine and works as you would expect:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestGeneric
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GenericClass<Integer> generic = new GenericClass<Integer>(7);
        String stringFromList = generic.getStringList().get(0);
    }

    static class GenericClass<A>
    {
        private A objA;
        private List<String> stringList;

        GenericClass(A objA)
        {
            this.objA = objA;
            stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
            stringList.add("A string");
            stringList.add("Another string");
        }

        A getObjA()
        {
            return objA;
        }

        List<String> getStringList()
        {
            return stringList;
        }
    }
}
```

but if you change the type of the variable generic to GenericClass (note no type parameters) compilation fails with the message "incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String".

This issue seems to happen with any generic class that contains a generic object with a concrete type parameter. A few Google searches haven't turned up anything and the JLS mentions nothing about this scenario? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in javac?

Comment: I can recreate it too. I think you may have found a little glitch in the Java compiler.

Comment: Strange.  Splitting up the line in question (`List<String> stringList=generic.getStringList(); String stringFromList=stringList.get(0);`) compiles OK.  At least that should serve as a workaround.

Comment: @ajb yes is does. Although you do get an unchecked warning but there's no way around that.

Comment: I'm pouring over the bytecode generated, but I see literally *no* difference between the two.  This is tricky.  Very interesting.

Comment: It's almost definitely a compiler bug then. I would hazard a guess that javac is not checking the return types of methods with generic return types properly if a reference to a class with a type parameter doesn't have a type parameter.

Comment: Deleted comments because I think I was mistaken earlier. My apologies.

Comment: @ajb That compiles because you can assign a raw type to anything without an explicit cast.

Comment: I found a somewhat related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885920/java-difference-between-list-and-listobject). As already stated, this is intended behavior, but it's another source -- this time, from Joshua Bloch and Bob Lee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raw type `GenericClass` is considered like erased, including generic types that are not declared by the class. So `getStringList` returns a raw `List` instead of a parameterized `List<String>`.

I've found it difficult to find one thing in the Java specification to point to for this but it is normal behavior.

Here is another example.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;

        // this compiles
        s = new Generic<Object>().get();
        // so does this
        s = new Generic<Object>().<String>get();

        // this doesn't compile
        s = new Generic().get();
        // neither does this
        s = new Generic().<String>get();
    }
}

class Generic<A> {
    <B> B get() { return null; }
}
```

Both `A` and `B` are erased, yet `B` is declared by a method. It is curious.

This kind of surprise nuance is why it is so obligatory to warn against using raw types.

Comment: Makes sense but yet another confusing nuance of Java's generics system :D It seems that if a generic class is referenced without generics javac automatically assumes the code is meant to be pre-1.5 compatible and erases all generics at the start. The best workaround when a generic class is being put into and retrieved from a pre-generic class (for me it was a JTable) is to use a reference with unbounded wildcards - <?> - so the object is obviously generic.

Comment: @ajb's answer has the relevant references to the jls if anyone who sees this is interested

Answer (score 3):

Following up on @Radiodef's answer, I may have found the JLS language behind this:

From §15.12.2.6 (SE8):

> The invocation type of a most specific accessible and applicable
>   method is a method type (§8.2) expressing the target types of the
>   invocation arguments, the result (return type or void) of the
>   invocation, and the exception types of the invocation. It is
>   determined as follows:

What this means is that once the compiler figures out what method it's calling, it then determines several properties collectively called the *method type*.  One of those properties is the return type, which becomes the type of the expression (the method invocation); that's the only one we're interested in here.

Using the original example, in which the method (`getStringList`) is not generic:

> If the chosen method is not generic, then:
>
> If unchecked conversion was necessary for the method to be applicable,
>   the parameter types of the invocation type are the parameter types of
>   the method's type, **and the return type** and thrown types **are given by
>   the erasures of the return type** and thrown types **of the method's type**.  [emphasis mine]

"Unchecked conversion" means casting a raw type to a parameterized type (§5.1.9).  I couldn't find a specific definition of when "unchecked conversion [is] necessary for [a] method to be applicable".  But in the form `object.method`, the first step in determining applicability is to determine the class or interface to search (§15.12.1), which is the class of the `object`, and what's probably going on is that since `generic` (in `generic.getStringList()`) has a raw type `GenericClass`, and the class we need to search is `GenericClass<A>`, this amounts to an unchecked conversion that is necessary for the method to be applicable.  I'm not 100% sure I'm right, though.

But assuming that I got this right, that means that the above paragraph applies, and thus the return type of the invocation is the erasure of the return type of the method's type.  Thus the type of `generic.getStringList()` is `List`, not `List<String>`, as @Radiodef pointed out.  The way the rule is written, it doesn't matter that the type parameter being erased from `List<String>` has nothing to do with the type parameters that were missing from the raw type; tightening up the rule to erase types when they need to be erased, but not in cases like this, would probably be very difficult.

So once the return type is seen as `List` and not `List<String>`, then unless it's cast back to a `List<String>` or assigned to something declared as `List<String>`, it will be treated as a `List` and the return type of a `get` call will be an `Object`.

The rule I quoted is for a non-generic method.  For a generic method, as in @Radiodef's example, the actual rule that applies is a couple paragraphs above the one I quoted, but what it says about the return type is the same as for non-generic methods.