# Difference between List<Object> and List

Tags: java, list

What is the difference between this lines:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

and

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

As i understand, all is object and when you do just List list, you just mentioned that.

Comment: The second list is of _raw type_ and the first list is type `Object`. Aside from that there's also `List<?>` and `List<? extends Object>`.

Comment: Is there a difference between List<Object> and List<? extends Object>?

Comment: Semantically, yes. Practically, not really. I'm waiting for a code expert to provide a more depthful answer.

Comment: Well, crap. Actually, exact dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885920/java-difference-between-list-and-listobject). Somehow missed that earlier. Flagged the wrong target, but this question is still a dupe.

Comment: @user3580294 I flagged that for you. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Unihedron Not sure how helpful it would be since OP already accepted, but thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately both statements are same. In this case there is no difference since every class in java extends Object.

You'll see the difference , if you take any specific object other than `Object`.

For ex:

```
List<String>  vs List
```

Comment: The statements will result in references with the same behavior, but the effects in the code elsewhere will not be the same...

Answer (score 6):

In practical terms there is no difference, they both compile down to the exact same code.

`List<Object>` though is showing that you have thought about what will go in the list and know it could be anything, whereas `List` on its own shows nothing.

Comment: Side note: you *can* see a difference if you use raw types with other generic code, as the raw type will cause generic checks in interacting code to be skipped.

Answer (score 3):

Java has been very good at keeping backwards compatibility between its releases.  Some would say, too good ;)

When Generics was added Sun put a lot of effort into making previous versions of Java work in just the same way.  They also made sure that Generics was part of the Java compiler, and not the JVM.  So a few oddities show through, and this is one of them.

The result is that the two are practically identical.  All in the name of backwards compatibility of Java language versions.

Comment: Not strictly true. Raw types will cause generic checks to be skipped in other parts of the code, leading to errors that you can't get with `<Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

While you won't see a difference in the how the `List`/`ArrayList` itself behaves, the use of raw types can impact *other* areas of your program, as *all* generic checks involving the code in question are skipped.

Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254210/strange-generics-behaviour-being-erased-early) question for example. From the accepted answer:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;

        // this compiles
        s = new Generic<Object>().get();
        // so does this
        s = new Generic<Object>().<String>get();

        // this doesn't compile
        s = new Generic().get();
        // neither does this
        s = new Generic().<String>get();
    }
}

class Generic<A> {
    <B> B get() { return null; }
}
```

Note how when the class `Generic` is parameterized with `<Object>`, you can compile the code just fine, but when you use the raw type the *unrelated* generic type `B` declared *inside* `Generic` is *also* erased, thus causing compile-time errors as `Object` can't be assigned to `String`.

So there *is* a difference -- when using raw types, you don't get *any* checks. If you use `<Object>`, the compiler will still perform type checks in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 1):

There's only a fool's difference. Using `List<Object>` and the non-generic `List` is silly, because what are you going to do with it?

Normally, you use a `List` to group related items and later, loop over them in some way and perform some common operations or extract some common information for every item.

This makes at least some sense:

```
List<Car> cars = getMeTheCars();
for(Car c : cars) {
    System.out.println(c.getName() + " is a car.");
}
```

If there are a bunch of different, unrelated types in your list, you get something horrible like this:

```
List<Object> obs = getMeTheObjects();
for(Object o : obs) {
    if(o instanceof String) { ... }
    if(o instanceof DateTime) { ... }
    if(o instanceof Integer) { ... }
    if(o instanceof Double) { ... }
    if(o instanceof Decimal) { ... }
    if(o instanceof SomeWeirdCustomClass) { ... }
    if(o instanceof SomeOtherClass) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically only the type differs. When you use List Object you are using the Object type (in this case). When you dont say  the list will be default made to be RAW type. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`List` which is Rawtype is not exactly the same thing as `List<Object>`. As already mentioned `List` is a java legacy code and since backward compatibility is a major concern in Java, the usage of Rawtypes such as `List` is still permitted, whereas `List<Object>` is a List of Objects. If your using the `List` class methods on both objects you'll notice that they behave the sameway, there is not difference. But if you try to do something like this in with JDK 8+ for instance:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> strings = objects; //Compilation error
```

You'll get a compiler error, whereas the bellow code works fine:

```
List raws = new ArrayList();
List<String> string = raws; // No compilation errors
```

The reason the second example works is for people who maintain the legacy code that is using `List` for instance. They can affect it to concret classes and work with them instead of keep working with the Rawtype Class.

From java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) :

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible
>   to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or
>   the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a
>   parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between `List` and `List<T>` is:

1. `List` is a raw type and thus can contain an object of any type whereas `List<T>` 
   may contain an object of type T or subtype of T.
2. We can assign a list object of any type to a raw type
   `List` reference variable, whereas we can only assign a list object of type `<T>` to a reference variable of type `List<T>`.Eg:

```
 List list=new ArrayList();                         //works fine
 List<String> list1=new ArrayList();                //works fine
 List<Animal> animals=new ArrayList<Animal>();      //works fine 
 List<Animal> dogs=new ArrayList<Dog>();            // compile-time error
```