# How does groupingBy work when classifier returns a List?

Tags: java, oop, java-stream, type-erasure

Consider [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58305875/10255450)

I have a few questions:

1. How does it work? Does `groupingBy()` check if the returned value from the `classifier` is a `List` and compare each and every item? That doesn't sound like a typical Java function to me
2. How can `List` contain different variable types? Does the compiler treat it like a `List<Object>`?
3. Is it anti-pattern to use `List`?

Comment: "That doesn't sound like a typical Java function to me" Why not? What is your definition of a "typical Java function"?

Comment: @Sweeper, typically you would need to implement `Comparator`

Comment: Your last question is a bit opinion-based. I would suggest that you remove it.

Comment: @Hulk, that doesn't make sense to me. If the is what it does then every call to `equal()`will yield `false`

Comment: @yaseco Why do you think so?

Comment: Every call the to classifier generates a new `List`. Two lists can never be equal (i.e. `l1.equals(l2)` is always `false`)

Comment: @Hulk, for some reason that is new to me but it makes sense actually

Comment: for completeness, can you also answer (2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hulk already said, there's absolutely no magic involved here. The `List` is compared with the `equals` method, just like any other object would.

To answer your second question, the type of items within a list can be controlled with generics. It's too bad they actually use a *raw type* in the answer you linked to. One should have used `List<?>` instead, but `List<Object>` would also have been fine.

Typically, the underlying array of a list implementation uses `Object[]` (at least for `ArrayList` is this the case).

A `List<Object>` can only contain `Object` instances, but guess what, all objects in the Java language are `Object`s, so that list can contain any object.

#### Immutability

It is important that the keys of a map (in this case `List`) are *immutable*. The way a typical `Map` works, is that it relies on the keys not being changed. Fortunately, the author of the linked post uses `List::of`, which returns an *unmodifiable* list.

Related: [Are mutable hashmap keys a dangerous practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice)

---

<sup>The author of the linked post used a `List` as key, in which he stored the fields to use as classifier. I would propose an alternative solution to using a list so select multiple fields to use as classifier. I would create a `record` instead, to make the intent clear of creating a classifier: `record AgeAndNameClassifier(int age, String name) { }` and then grouping by: `groupingBy(item -> new AgeAndNameClassifier(item.getAge(), item.getName())...`</sup>

Comment: awesome, all clear now!

Comment: It’s worth noting that all lists have [the same contract regarding equality](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#hashCode()). You can use mutable keys, as long as you still treat them like immutable, which is crucial when using Java 8, which has no `List.of(…)` so `Arrays.asList(…)` was the simplest solution. These list keys are a work-around which indeed becomes unnecessary when using a newer Java version with `record` types.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is that the value returned by the classifier is compared using the `equals()`-method, which in case of a `List` is specified:

[`List.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are *equal*.

Actually, the comparing and equals-invoking is done by the underlying `Map` implementation.

Your second question

> How can `List` contain different variable types? Does the compiler treat it like a `List<Object>`?

Not quite, it is a raw type, see
[Java difference between List and List<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885920/java-difference-between-list-and-listobject)
for some differences.

As for your third question,

> Is it anti-pattern to use List?

This is answered here:
[ArrayList as key in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973596/arraylist-as-key-in-hashmap/37477576)

summary: it is risky, as is using mutable types as keys in general. `hashCode` must not change after insertion in a `HashMap`, and that means that neither the list itself nor any item in the list may be modified in a way that might change the results of `hashCode()` or `equals()`.